# Show/Hide via Checkbox Hides on Mobile?

Tags: html, css

I've created a basic expandable region where clicking a checkbox shows an embedded textbox. Clicking the checkbox a second time to uncheck, the textbox is then hidden. This works as expected with no bugs on desktop view. However, on mobile, if you tap the checkbox, and then tap the textbox to enter some text, it reads it as a tap on the checkbox and thus the textbox is then hidden, but will accept input.

I believe this is due to the fact that the textbox is a child element of the checkbox element, but I'm unsure as to how to prevent this from happening. I made it a child to ensure I could show and hide it based on the state of the checkbox via `css` instead of `JavaScript` managing however many of these I have on a page.

```css
* { transition: 0.2s all linear; }
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #333;
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #333, #999);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #333, #999);
 overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.textbox {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 25px;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 200;
}
.placeholder {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5px;
 bottom: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #ddd;
 z-index: 201;
}
.textbox input[type=text] {
 position: relative;
 flex: 1;
 padding: 5px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #0af;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 z-index: 202;
}
.textbox input[type=text]:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.textbox input[type=text]:focus {
 outline-width: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.textbox input[type=text]:focus + .placeholder,
.textbox input[type=text]:valid + .placeholder {
 font-size: 15px;
 top: -25px;
 color: #0af;
}
.textbox.invalid > input[type=text] + .placeholder { color: #f33; }
.textbox.invalid input[type=text] { border-bottom: 2px solid #f33; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .textbox input[type=text] { font-size: 8vw; }
 .textbox .placeholder { font-size: 6vw !important; }
}

.checkbox {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 40px;
}
.checkbox > input {
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox.disabled {
 color: #999;
 cursor: default;
}
.checkbox.disabled > .checkmark {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 border: 1px solid #999;
}
.checkbox > input:checked + .checkmark {
 background-color: #0af;
 border: 1px solid #0af;
}
.checkbox:not(.disabled):hover { color: #0af; }
.checkbox:not(.disabled):hover > .checkmark { border: 1px solid #0af; }
.checkmark {
 position: absolute;
 top: 8px;
 left: 10px;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
}
.checkmark:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 left: 7px;
 width: 7px;
 height: 15px;
 border: solid white;
   border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
 display: none;
 content: "";
 animation: build-checkmark 0.2s;
}
.checkbox input:checked + .checkmark:after {
 display: block;
}
@keyframes build-checkmark {
 0% {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
 }
 100% {
  width: 7px;
  height: 15px;
 }
}

.expandable-checkbox-region {
 display: none;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.checkbox > input:checked ~ .expandable-checkbox-region {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <label class="checkbox">12345678
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  <div class="expandable-checkbox-region">
   <div class="textbox">
     <input type="text" required />
     <label class="placeholder">Field Name</label>
   </div>
      <div class="textbox">
     <input type="text" required />
     <label class="placeholder">Field Name</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </label>
</div>
```

---

Is there a way to ensure the expand/collapse works on mobile views as experienced on desktop views without using JavaScript?

Steps to Reproduce:

- Desktop

  1. Click Checkbox
  2. Click Textbox
  3. Textbox doesn't hide.
- Mobile

  1. Tap Checkbox
  2. Tap Textbox
  3. Textbox hides but shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<label for="#textbox">` and giving the corresponding `id` to your textbox as `<input id="textbox">`. This way when you tap the `label`, it should make your textbox active. Similarly for `checkbox`

> I believe this is due to the fact that the textbox is a child element of the checkbox element, but I'm unsure as to how to prevent this from happening.

I don't think it is true as every editable element have their own `onFocus` events, irrespective of its parent or child. For eg, if you click on `#textbox`, it should be `focus`ed, not its parent element.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @PerpetualJ is it the same problem or have we made some improvements? If not, you might just need to increase the margin between the both for the corresponding `device-width`

Comment: With this in place no matter which level I assign the IDs they don't even open at all.